Who established the tefilas Mussaf?
Many people know the aggadeta in gemara Berakhos 26b regarding the origin of daily tefilos:

The Gemara comments: It was taught in a baraita in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yosei, son of Rabbi Ḥanina, and it was taught in a baraita in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi. The Gemara elaborates: It was taught in a baraita in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yosei, son of Rabbi Ḥanina: Abraham instituted the morning prayer (shacharis), as it is stated when Abraham came to look out over Sodom the day after he had prayed on its behalf: “And Abraham rose early in the morning to the place where he had stood before the Lord” (Genesis 19:27), and from the context as well as the language utilized in the verse, the verb standing means nothing other than prayer, as this language is used to describe Pinehas’ prayer after the plague, as it is stated: “And Pinehas stood up and prayed and the plague ended” (Psalms 106:30). Clearly, Abraham was accustomed to stand in prayer in the morning.
Isaac instituted the afternoon prayer (mincha), as it is stated: “And Isaac went out to converse [lasuaḥ] in the field toward evening” (Genesis 24:63), and conversation means nothing other than prayer, as it is stated: “A prayer of the afflicted when he is faint and pours out his complaint [siḥo] before the Lord” (Psalms 102:1). Obviously, Isaac was the first to pray as evening approached, at the time of the afternoon prayer.
Jacob instituted the evening prayer (maariv/arvit), as it is stated: “And he encountered [vayifga] the place and he slept there for the sun had set” (Genesis 28:11). The word encounter means nothing other than prayer, as it is stated when God spoke to Jeremiah: “And you, do not pray on behalf of this nation and do not raise on their behalf song and prayer, and do not encounter [tifga] Me for I do not hear you” (Jeremiah 7:16). Jacob prayed during the evening, after the sun had set.

While the question is essentially similar to the question "Who instituted the Musaf prayer?", I am asking for a source in חז"ל, not commentary. Is there a similar statement in chazal (including kabbala) regarding the origin of tefilas mussaf, attributing it to either forefathers, foremothers, or the shevatim?

Related neilah https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/131177/759

Rashi on the same daf: תפלת המוספין מאן תקנה - אלא ע"כ רבנן אסמכינהו אקרבנות וכי עיינו במוספין ולא מצאו תפלה כנגדה עמדו הם ותקנוה . It was instituted by the Rabanan.

@Deuteronomy Thank you. R' Moshe Polter in the book "Shevatim" quotes R'Munk who supposedly references Zohar that Rachel instituted Musaf. Either there could be such a source that Rashi did not know about or it may show that Zohar is later than the times of Gemara.

Interesting... I see here citing the ליקוטים ישנים (?) that specifically Musaf Rosh Hodesh (based on ראשי חדשים לעמך ) is attributed to רחל. IMHO it sounds like a later folksy explanation rather than anything firmly sourced but the idea is out there in the velt for whatever it's worth...

These are in regards to the times of day for praying not the prayers themselves. The amidah (including musaf) were instituted by the chachamim

The זוהר חדש affiliates the אושפיזין to the קרנבות מוסף of Shabbos and all the Yomim Tovim. A little interpretation is needed for some of them but it appears to me as such:
שבת כנגד יוסף - Shabbos relates to Yosef
פסח כנגד אברהם - Pesach relates to Avraham
שבועות כנגד יעקב - Shevous relates to Yaakov
ראש השנה כנגד יצחק - Rosh Hashana relates to Yitzchak
יום כיפור כנגד משה - Yom Kippur relates to Moshe
סוכות כנגד אהרון - Sukkos relates to Aharon
ראש חודש כנגד דוד - Rosh Chodesh relates to Dovid

Nice. How is the word כנגד related to the word תקן? Also why is the Shemini Atzeres skipped?

@YDJ Based on the fact that chassidus (specifically R’ Tzadok Hakohen) associates Shmini Atzeres with Shlomo as the eighth Ushpizin, I would theorize that its musaf is also kneged Shlomo.
